# Using file_get_contents with basic auth and SSL

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I'm attempting a `GET` request using SSL and basic auth using the `file_get_contents` function:

```
$username = "XXXXXXXXXX";
$password = "XXXXXXXXXX";

$url = "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/authorization/api/v1/token?url=https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api";

$context = stream_context_create(array("http" => array("header" => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password"))));

$data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

echo $data;
```

Here's the error message I get:

> Warning: file_get_contents(https://stream.watsonplatform.net/authorization/api/v1/token?url=https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 500 Server Error...

I've already confirmed that `openssl` is enabled:

[image]

And we might as well get this out of the way up-front:

**Why don't you just use cURL?**

I could. But I also want to figure out why `file_get_contents` isn't working. I like the relative simplicity of `file_get_contents`. Call me crazy.

Comment: With an other HTTPS URL without basic auth, does it work?

Comment: i can hit the url with my browser, i cant with `file_get_contents`, i suspect they are detecting the automated attempt. with curl you can make it look a lot more like a 'real' person access, you dont have those options with `file_get_contents`

Comment: @AnthonyB yes, it works with `https://google.com` for example.

Comment: @smith interesting...so it may be unique to this endpoint? I'll give a basic cURL setup a try and see if I run into the same issue.

Comment: that's my guess, i only did some basic testing for you.

Comment: In the context, try to set the user agent. If you set the same user agent as a Firefox for example the website will no longer detect an automated request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Curiosity is a good thing so it's cool to dig this problem without falling back to cURL before fixing this problem.

```
<?php
$username = "XXXXXXXXXX";
$password = "XXXXXXXXXX";

$url = "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/authorization/api/v1/token?url=https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api";

$context = stream_context_create(array(
    "http" => array(
        "header" => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password"),
        "protocol_version" => 1.1, //IMPORTANT IS HERE
    )));

$data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

echo $data;
```

The fact is the server does not support HTTP/1.0. So you haven't any problem with SSL/TLS nor with your user agent. It is just the server that support HTTP from 1.1.

As said in the [stream_context_create](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php#context.http.protocol-version) documentation the default *protocol_version* used in *stream_context_create* is 1.0. That's why you got an error 500.

Comment: This worked! +1 and accepted. It's not clear to me why someone downvoted...

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted, and I would like he/her leave a comment. But thanks, I'm glad to help you!

Answer (score -1):

EDIT : My bad, don't see this is not curl. Try with this

```
$username = "XXXXXXXXXX";
$password = "XXXXXXXXXX";

$url = "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/authorization/api/v1/token?url=https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api";

$context = stream_context_create(array(
"http" => array("header" => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password")), 
"ssl"=>array(
    "verify_peer"=>false,
    "verify_peer_name"=>false,
)));

$data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

echo $data;
```

Comment: did you test it? good idea to test your code before posting it as an 'answer'

Comment: Cant test without logins and cant comment directly

Comment: If you are not sure, please post a comment instead of an answer.
I've tested your code and I get the error 500 as the OP. If your solution was the one, we would get an error 401 because of invalid credentials.

Comment: I know, but i can't comment (<50 )

Comment: Thanks for your time, but this solution does not work.